Multiple request.POST key/values into string via function
I am trying to write values from a request.POST to a string format.
By default, these always start with "epochs-NUMBER-".
Therefore, I should draw a For loop so that a new line is created for each number.
Edit:
The request originates from a dynamic Django form, which has no static elements (the epochs are dynamic). It's a standard Python POST request. The only thing these elements have in common is that they all start the same way (epochs-number-etc.). The request is processed via string (nmea_sting-Function) into a file using Python.
The complete request looks like that. But I only need the 'epochs-NUMBER-' values
csrfmiddlewaretoken=hJmSuP3O6GmtwBeJhfqb99LaCVOKxgngGNIEqoqhQQR7tQELUVGHeXRXxfnRE1Ah&base-TOTAL_FORMS=1&base-INITIAL_FORMS=0&base-MIN_NUM_FORMS=0&base-MAX_NUM_FORMS=1000&base-0-time=25.06.2024+13%3A36%3A00&base-0-show_differences=on&base-0-show_null=1&source=Manual&epochs-TOTAL_FORMS=3&epochs-INITIAL_FORMS=3&epochs-MIN_NUM_FORMS=0&epochs-MAX_NUM_FORMS=1000&unit_selector=m&unit_selector=m&unit_selector=m&unit_selector=m&epochs-0-target_name=250.01.G&epochs-0-easting=55555&epochs-0-northing=5555&epochs-0-height=555&epochs-0-azimuth=&epochs-0-zenithangle=&epochs-0-slope_dist=&epochs-1-target_name=170.01.G&epochs-1-easting=44646&epochs-1-northing=6554&epochs-1-height=544&epochs-1-azimuth=&epochs-1-zenithangle=&epochs-1-slope_dist=&epochs-2-target_name=150.01.G&epochs-2-easting=78979878&epochs-2-northing=4645&epochs-2-height=455&epochs-2-azimuth=&epochs-2-zenithangle=&epochs-2-slope_dist=
The request looks like that:

Edit:
One target is epochs-0-etc, the next is epochs-1-etc. and so on. My solution sadly works only for one target at the moment (epochs-0-etc)
def nmea_string(self, request, target_name):
   my_dict = {}
   keys = []
   values = []
   target_raw_string = ("PTER," + self.short_name + "_TRG," + target_name + "," +
                        self.time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + "," + str(self.status_target))
   for key, value in request.POST.items():
       keys.append(key)
       values.append(value)
   for i in range(len(keys)):
       my_dict.update({keys[i]: values[i]})
   
   for k, v in my_dict.items():
       if k.startswith('epochs-0-'):
           if v == '':
               v = '-9999.999900'
           if k.startswith('epochs-0-target_name'):
               target_raw_string += "," + v
           else:
               target_raw_string += "," + v + ",0.000000"

   tg_checksum = self.get_checksum(target_raw_string)
   tg_nmea_string = "$" + target_raw_string + "*" + tg_checksum + "\n"

   nmea_string += tg_nmea_string

   return nmea_string

The end result should look a bit like this:
$PTER,TS_TRG,250.01.G,2024-04-22 23:00:00,129,675666.252000,0.000000,252132.398000,0.000000,412.137000,0.000000,-9999.999900,0.000000,-9999.999900,0.000000,-9999.999900,0.000000*1F
$PTER,TS_TRG,170.01.G,2024-04-22 23:00:00,129,675704.440000,0.000000,252162.055000,0.000000,412.341000,0.000000,-9999.999900,0.000000,-9999.999900,0.000000,-9999.999900,0.000000*1A


So what do you need? Please add it to the question, now it's unclear.

Hello, what is the goal of your function nmea_string please ? It is unclear what the problem is.

where does your request come from? With what framework are you receiving your request on python side? Can you modify how the request is sent? Please share more info in your question

what is an "Epochs target"? How would the request be adapted for multi target epochs?

Use regular expressions to check if it's an epoch, and what the epoch number and field name is:
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    if not k.startswith("epochs-"):
        continue
    match = re.match(r"epochs-(\d+)-(.+)", k)
    if not match:
       continue
    epoch, field_name = match.groups()
    ...  # rest of your processing


Side note:
The query string looks like it was made from a formset. Why not simply validate the formset and then generate the string from the cleaned data of the individual forms? The forms will be in the right order, and the cleaned_data contains just the bare field names, without any of the prefixes, so you don't have to use a regex. The values will have been validated too.
Maybe something like this:
formset = YourFormsetClass(request.POST)
if formset.is_valid():
    for form in formsets.forms:
        target_raw_string = ""
        for k, v in form.cleaned_data.items():
            if v == '':
                v = '-9999.999900'
            if k == "target_name":
                target_raw_string  += "," + v
            else:
                target_raw_string += "," + v + ",0.000000"


regex are not best suited for this job as they are highly inefficient

If you are concerned about CPU time, you can check whether they dictionary key starts with epochs- before running the regex against the key. This way you can assure that the regex will apply, at least partially, and at that point the difference between using something like split("-") or the regex will become negligible. I'd guess that the regex might even be faster than split then.

Without using regex, you could have the following:
from typing import Any

def find_epochs_metrics(request_data: dict[str, Any]):
    for k, v in request_data.items():
        if not k.startswith("epochs-"):
            continue

        k_split = k.split("-")
        epoch_n = k_split[1]

        if not epoch_n.isdigit():
            continue

        field_name = k_split[2]

        ...

You should try to minimize your usage of regex since they are inefficient, and hard to maintain.

If the request data contains items such as epochs-TOTAL_FORMS (as the request query string suggests it does), then this will raise a ValueError. Field names that contain a dash - will also be split up and thus mangled. You could try epoch_n, field_name = k[len("epochs-"):].split("-", 1) surrounded by a try except ValueError block. Personally, I'd prefer the readability of a short regex at that point.

you are right, I did not read the full request body, I only checked the picture of the data. I'll update the function to take this case into account. I still believe regex should be avoided when easy alternatives exist
